# Android set height of layout dynamically due to an absolutely positioned bottom navbar

Tags: android

I am stuck on trying to get a view to stop where the bottom navbar begins.

[image]

I have a bunch of blue boxes in a ScrollView. You can see in the image that my last box is getting overshadowed by the bottom navbar. But I don't want the contents to go past the bottom navbar. The problem is due to the bottom navbar being constrained to the bottom absolutely, so the other elements above it just ignore that it's even there (similar to how HTML absolutely positioned elements work).

How can I code it to where the blue boxes won't go past the bottom navbar?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your layout, you have one of two ways in dealing with this problem.

### 1. Hide `BottomAppBar` on content scroll

Assuming that the parent layout is `CoordinatorLayout`, you can hide the `BottomAppBar` automatically when there's scroll going down the content by adding `app:hideOnScroll="true"` to the `BottomAppBar`.

---

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        ...
        app:hideOnScroll="true" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### 2. Add bottom padding to your `ScrollView`

Naive way, add a bottom padding to your `ScrollView` to, well, add bottom padding.

```xml
<ScrollView
    ...
    android:paddingBottom="?actionBarSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <!-- Put the boxes here and make all of them have a height 0dp, and layout weight as 1 -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- the navigation box goes here with a specific height-->
</LinearLayout>
```

This will ensure all the box item have equal height and also occupy the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I do in example. please check the following files. This will solve your problem

Activity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img20" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Sign In" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Register" />
            <Button
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Some element" />
            <Button
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Other" />
            <Button
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Last" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_main.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
    android:title="favroit"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
    android:title="shedule"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_music"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_black_24dp"
    android:title="music"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

[image]